# Confluent.Kafka for UWP application. (HoloLens)

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, uwp, confluent-platform, librdkafka

I am creating a UWP application for Hololens and I need the Kafka-Client. I used the pre-built .dlls from confluent-kafka-dotnet (*https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet*) and librdkafka (*https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka*) but when I run the application I get that error:

> "Unable to load DLL 'kernel32.dll': The specified module could not be
>   found."

I think the problem is on librdkafka.dll because the files are released for standard architectures like x86 or x64 (Desktop) not for UWP.

So, could you give me some suggestions how to procceed with that problem? It's needed to rebuild the librdkafka as VC++ project for Universal Windows Platform ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried opening.a github issue with this question?

Comment: Yeah, for sure. The problem is the releases are built for desktop applications and not for UWP. Finally, I used rest-api Confluent Kafka over Http-requests.

Comment: Note: "Confluent Kafka" is not a thing. REST Proxy works fine with Apache Kafka (which is all that is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the releases are built for desktop applications and not for UWP. Finally, I used REST proxy for Apache Kafka over HTTP requests. You can follow the [link](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/quickstart.html).